# Composer turn off generation of classmap autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on a project which contains couple of parts written in different languages. One of these parts is a PHP application. When distributing the project there is a phase to distrib this PHP app. I use Phing for that. So apart from other dependencies, I have

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.3.13",
  "phing/phing": "2.7.*"
}
```

As `composer.json` in Phing package suggests, Composer creates autoload_classmap entries for Phing. There are some Phing targets that copy vendor libraries further, but they don't copy Phing itself (it's not a runtime dependency for PHP project itself). As a consequence, there are many entries in autoload_classmap that are problematic. My application itself uses classmaps so I want to use the mechanism but not for all packages.

Is it possible to suppress generation of classmap entries on a **per package basis** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a hen-and-egg problem, but I think Phing does not belong into the softwares dependencies, so it has to be taken out. Problem with the classmap solved.

Where does it belong? It is infrastructure you have to install to deploy or distribute the software. Phing should be installed on the machine executing the deployment, or anywhere else where it is needed, but this is part of the infrastructure requirement for this machine.

You can use Composer to install Phing globally (it's way better than using PEAR for this). Or you can create a deployment project that includes Phing, probably other stuff, and has the task to deploy/distribute that software.

Comment: Thanks for affirming my suspicions. I will do exactly that with Phing but I find the problem bigger as you cannot run away from using two non-namespaced packages with classmap which will eventually collide, but I guess it's more of a problem of the packages themselves. So the original question stays - is this possible with Composer ?